# How to slice every element of nparray and store it in new nparray?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

If this is the nparray i have

```
arr_str = np.array(['10', '100', '301', '23423'])
```

I want to convert into like this using slicing
get the last char in the str a[-1] where a is element in nparray

```
arr_slice = np.array(['0', '0', '1', '3'])
```

just like how we can add numbers to each element of nparray like

```
arr_str.asType(int) + 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a list comprehension?

```
>>> np.array([x[-1] for x in arr_str])
array(['0', '0', '1', '3'], dtype='<U1')
```

Alternatively you can use the `%` modulo operator:

```
>>> arr_str.astype(int) % 10
array([0, 0, 1, 3])
```

Comment: hey what if it's a multi-dimensional array

Answer (score 2):

this short answer for you, try this:

```
np.array(list(map(lambda x : int(x[-1]) , list(arr_str)))) + 5
# array([5, 5, 6, 8])
```